# How to ensure a js array respects element order when I add them to a containing array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am looping thru an array and trying to find where two elements sum to 10.

I find the correct match pairs... but for two of them the order is not retained when they are added.

I expect to get

```
[ [9,1], [6,4], [3,7], [7,3], [6,4], [1,9] ]
```

but I get

```
[ [9,1], [6,4], [3,7], [3,7], [6,4], [9,1] ]

i.e.  =>                ^^^           ^^^
are different
```

Why do the two pairs indicated have their order backwards ?

```
  newNums = [];
  nums.forEach(num1 => {
    nums.forEach(num2 => {
      num1Position = nums.indexOf(num1);
      num2Position = nums.indexOf(num2);
      if (num1 + num2 === 10 && num2Position > num1Position )  {
        newNums.push([num1, num2]);
      }
    })
  })
  return newNums;
}

result = sumTwoNumbersIsTen([9,6,3,7,3,6,4,2,0,1,9])
console.log(result); // should be [ [9,1], [6,4], [3,7], [7,3], [6,4], [1,9] ]
// but I get                      [ [9,1], [6,4], [3,7], [3,7], [6,4], [9,1] ]
//
```

Answer (score 3):

You could iterate with indices and omit parts who are not valid.

BTW, it is a good idea to declare all variables.

```js
const sumTwoNumbersIsTen = nums => {
    const newNums = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < nums.length - 1; i++) {
        const num1 = nums[i];
        for (let j = i + 1; j < nums.length; j++) {
            const num2 = nums[j];
            if (num1 + num2 === 10) {
                newNums.push([num1, num2]);
            }
        }
    }
    return newNums;
};

console.log(sumTwoNumbersIsTen([9, 6, 3, 7, 3, 6, 4, 2, 0, 1, 9])); // [[9, 1], [6, 4], [3, 7], [7, 3], [6, 4], [1, 9]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you're using the wrong positions. Instead of taking the position of the element from the current iteration, which `forEach` passes to your callback, you are *searching* for an index in the array where the value could be found. For duplicate values, this will always find the first index, not the one you want (and also it's horribly inefficient).

```
newNums = [];
nums.forEach((num1, num1Position) => {
  nums.forEach((num2, num2Position) => {
    if (num1 + num2 === 10 && num2Position > num1Position )  {
      newNums.push([num1, num2]);
    }
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that there are (for example) two 9s in the array, and `.indexOf` only finds the index of the *first* occurence.

You can solve this by not using `indexOf` and instead exploiting that the callback to `forEach` can take a second parameter which is the element's index:

```js
function sumTwoNumbersIsTen(nums) {
  newNums = [];
  nums.forEach((num1, num1Position) => {
    nums.forEach((num2, num2Position) => {
      if (num1 + num2 === 10 && num2Position > num1Position )  {
        newNums.push([num1, num2]);
      }
    })
  })
  return newNums;
}

result = sumTwoNumbersIsTen([9,6,3,7,3,6,4,2,0,1,9])
console.log(result);
```